# C++ templates facing overload mismatch issue. What is wrong in the code?

Tags: c++, templates

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class T>
inline void swap(T &i,T &j)
{
  T temp = i;
  i=j;
  j=temp;
}

int main ()
{
  int a = 2,b =5;
  swap(a,b);
  cout << "a=" <<a<< " b=" <<b<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

This is a simple swap program using templates. I am new to templates and wanted to learn how to use it.

Comment: Try renaming your method `myswap()` and skies will turn blue again ;) ...

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I did change the function name and it worked. But knowing the exact issue was more important and thanks for sharing.

Comment: That's the reason, why it's discouraged to use global `using namespace ...` statements.

Answer (score 1):

`using namespace std` is the problem. There is an `std::swap()` function that is causing the function call to become ambiguous.

Comment: ... and it's likely to be introduced from `#include <iostream>`!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. That was indeed the problem. So I changed the function name and it worked.

Comment: If I helped, it would be nice if you excepted the answer :)